# Is it okay to give <html> a background image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, background, tags

Or is this bad practice for some reason?

Many thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to clarify the definition of "Okay". @danontheline points out that this is invalid html. It will render but will be technically invalid.

Comment: It is very interesting question. I have to do some tests with JavaScript too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just add it to the body element you will get the same effect. Or if you are looking at double backgrounds you might want to look at the CSS3 component of being able to use this feature. (Although not compatible with all browser versions)

Comment: I'll be trying that then :) Apparently there is some debate about the validity of using the <html> tag for this.

Comment: There's the 'right way' and 'what works'.  Given you asked about best practice I avoided the duct tape.

Answer (score 2):

Given your question...

It is a bad practice.

A background for the entire body of the page should be applied to the body tag:

```
body { background-image:url('sunny.gif') }
```

It's the best practice.

Just note that if the image you're using is smaller than the screen, it will be repeated!

A commonly recommended practice is to also specify a matching background color as it will appear immediately (and then be replaced).

```
body { background-image:url('sunny.gif'); background-color:#b0c4de; }
```

Also a shortcut is:

```
body { background: #b0c4de; url('sunny'.jpg) } # could also add repeat/scroll/top
```

Here's the full list for background:

- background-attachment
- background-color
- background-image
- background-position
- background-repeat

Nice write-ups at: http://www.beginnersguidetohtml.com/references/css

Comment: I was actually planning on using CSS for this :)

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I'm not that much of a beginner anymore :D But I definitely appreciate the effort you did, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the html is much better place for background than body. The W3C recommendation is different. I think it is due to compatibility with very old browsers, like Internet Explorer 5.5, Netscape Navigator 4 or something much more exotic. In either case both places are valid.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/colors.html point 14.2
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-background-20110215/ point 3.11

There is small quirk.

1. If You set background on body end not on html, the browsers interpret this as background on html, not on body.
2. If You set background on html, everything works as expected.
3. If You set background on both html and body, You will probably see the body box is smaller than html box.

Comment: Hmmm interesting... I already fixed the problem using double backgrounds but I'll still try this out just for the sake of... ehh trying out.

Comment: Tailoring to < 1% of users is interesting... however many folks are doing that... but ignoring basics for mobile and tablets, now 10% of the market...

Comment: I don't see any problems with mobile.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is a problem. It works in older browsers. Although I would recommend that you don't add many other styles to the html tag, it tends to be a bit inconsistent across browsers.

Comment: Thanks! I want to try something with a double background of which one needs to be at the bottom of the page. I couldn't really figure it out so far so I hope the answer lies in using one bg in the <html> tag.

Answer (score -2):

W3C Schhols says its invalid:

> Core Attributes
>   Not valid in base, head, html, meta, param, script, style, and title
>   elements.

And the list of those not valid attributes is to find [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp)

Any reason why you don't give `<body>` the style attribute ?

Comment: Could you reference this in the W3 specifications? [I don't really trust W3Schools to be accurate in this case](http://w3fools.com/).